# Combine UIView and UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, swift2

Hi Is it possible to combine to combine a UIView with a UITableView and reference it as a single object? I currently have a both combined as a Stack, but I feel there is a better way to do it. Thanks

[image: screen shot]

Comment: can you provide an example showing how do you want to reference them? if is a uiview with a uitableview below more appropriate way would be using the uitablewview header

Comment: What is your objective in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two different objects, one property cannot reference two different views. You can however use an IBOutlet for both views in your ViewController, or within any ancestor view.

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!
}
```

Then, you can just drag a `reference outlet` for that specific view from Storyboard to the view controller. For information on that:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html

Note that I did not add a property for your UIView because I assumed it is already the main view of the controller. Similarly, you can subclass your main view, add an outlet for the table view, and use that as the reference outlet.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there are two way to resolve your require:
Option 1. use table view header view. I suppose you want to combine a view named `topView` with a table view. call `tableView.tableHeaderView = topView`
Option 2. add `topView` to table view as a subview, then adjust contentInset of table view. Just like:

```
    UIEdgeInsets tableViewInsets = self.tableView.contentInset;
    tableViewInsets.top = topView.frame.size.height;
    self.tableView.contentInset = tableViewInsets;
```